# UICollectionView loading and UINavigationController reset of view controllers

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uicollectionview

I have a UIViewController (which is my apps root view controller) that contains a UINavigationController that I reload using

```
- (void)presentSelectedViewController
{
    [[self navController] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [[self navController] setViewControllers:@[[self selectedViewController]] animated:NO];
}
```

`self.selectedViewController` is set through this:

```
- (void)setSelectedViewController:(UIViewController *)selectedViewController
{

    if (_selectedViewController != selectedViewController)
       {

        if ([selectedViewController isKindOfClass:[SNPStandInViewController class]])
           {
             Class newClass = [(SNPStandInViewController *)selectedViewController actualClass];
             if ([newClass class] == [SVWebViewController class])
                selectedViewController = [[[(SNPStandInViewController *)selectedViewController actualClass] alloc] initWithAddress:[PREFERENCES urlForDefaultSearchProvider]];
                else
                selectedViewController = [[[(SNPStandInViewController *)selectedViewController actualClass] alloc] init];

             if ([selectedViewController isKindOfClass:[SNPSettingsViewController class]])
                [(SNPSettingsViewController *)selectedViewController setDelegate:[self rootController]];
             }

        Class oldClass = [self.selectedViewController class];
        NSInteger oldControllerIndex = [self.viewControllers indexOfObject:self.selectedViewController];

        [self.selectedViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];

        [self.selectedViewController removeFromParentViewController];

        [(SNPStandardViewController *) self.selectedViewController releaseResources];

        [self willChangeValueForKey:@"selectedViewController"];
        _selectedViewController = selectedViewController;
        [self didChangeValueForKey:@"selectedViewController"];

        [self.viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:_selectedIndex withObject:selectedViewController];

        if (nil != oldClass && oldControllerIndex != NSNotFound)
           {
             [self.viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:oldControllerIndex withObject:[[SNPStandInViewController alloc] initWithClass:oldClass]];
             }

        [[self indexTableView] reloadData];
        }

    [self presentSelectedViewController];
}
```

(The standin view controller class is an `NSObject` subclass that basically holds the class of the view controller that should be there and creates it if selected -- though it is visually not a tab interface, think a tab interface where I don't want to have the actual view controllers that are not selected be created and in memory and running)

I have one view controller that has a `UICollectionView` in it and this is the default view controller that is set using the above code when the app first runs.  It runs fine and the `UICollectionView` loads its data before the `-(void)viewWillAppear:` of that view controller runs (a `-(void)loadView` implementation creates the `UICollectionView` and does a [uiCollectionViewInstance reloadData]).

If I select another view controller above, and then reselect the initial one (which is a new instance -- old instances when moved off of are destroyed), the `UICollectionView` does not load its data (even though the `loadView` routine creates it and calls `reloadData`) until after both `viewWillAppear:` and `viewDidAppear` actually run.  This is bad because I call a selection routine in `viewWillAppear:` to set a highlight in the collection view on the item that is the default selection [think a button bar type interface].

The same code path seems to run each time I create this view controller that contains the collection view (with extensive NSLog outputting to show the path).  So I assume that maybe something is happening in the actual routine that creates the new view controller and sets it as the active one in the `UINavigationController`

I am at a loss to know what to explore to see why this collection view has no visible cells after being created and reload data being called on it when it is created after being selected in my pseudo tab controller described above (but it works fine when set initially upon creation of the pseudo tab controller).

I don't know what else people want to see but I'd be happy to try and post more info, code, etc as necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the `-presentSelectedViewController` I added this after doing the `setViewControllers` and now it all works fine.

```
[[[self selectedViewController] view] setNeedsLayout];
[[[self selectedViewController] view] layoutIfNeeded];
```